# Zend Framework 2 route overlap

Tags: zend-framework2, routes, overlap

Let's say I want the user to be able to access his profile by typing something like 
www.test.com/hisname

I've added the following route to the routes array in my modules config file

```
        'profile' => array(
            'type' => 'segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route' => '/:user[/]',
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'User\Controller\User',
                    'action' => 'profile'       
                )
            )
        ),
```

and everything works fine until I want to access a page, for example www.test.com/about that has the following, easy to figure out, route

```
        'about' => array(
            'type' => 'segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route' => '/about[/]',
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Index',
                    'action' => 'about'     
                )
            )
        ),
```

The result is that it gets matched by the first route and redirects to the profile. I've thought about the order, but **these two routes are in different modules**

Any ideas? Should I use a pattern to exclude the "static" pages? I've thought of that as well but I will have to change it every time I make a new page.

Help me out felas!

Comment: It's last:in, first:out. So if you the route `about` is defined after your route `profile`, then about can be matched. If however `profile` is defined after `about`, then about will never be matched. When they are in different Modules, then it's simply about the Module load order.

Comment: Okay now I feel dumb, I mean how can I not think of that when I already know that the order matters.. bummer! Anyway thanks a lot, I guess that's the best solution for my issue :)